# How to invalidate session when client's IP address changes

Tags: java, spring-mvc, session, spring-security

I'm trying to invalidate a user session if user's IP address changes (I want to enforce that users stays on same IP address for whole duration of a session, or they need to re-authenticate). I would assume that there is a feature built into Spring Security to achieve this, but I can't seem to find it.

What would be to most elegant way implement this requirement (preferably through Spring Security's config)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I could not find any built-in feature in Spring Security to bind a session to IP, but it's easily implemented using a custom filter:

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) {
    boolean chainCompleted = implementEnforcement(request, response);
    if (!chainCompleted) {
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}

private boolean implementEnforcement(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    final String key = "enforcement.ip";
    HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
    if (session != null) {
        // we have a session
        String ip = request.getRemoteAddr();
        String ipInSession = session.getAttribute(key);
        if (ipInSession == null) {
            session.setAttribute(key, ip);
        } else {
            if (!ipInSession.equals(ip)) {
                // JSESSIONID is the same, but IP has changed
                // invalidate the session because there is a probability that it is
                // a session hijack
                session.invalidate();
                // a redirection to some page (probably to context root) may be added here
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

It remembers user's IP address and then compares current IP with the remembered one: if it differs, the session is destroyed.

Comment: It is old thread, but I hope this peice of info could be useful for people who may refer it in the future. If the request has `X-Forwarded-For` header, it would be better to get the client IP from the header instead of `request.getRemoteAddr()`. Refer this question for the difference between those two - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63617756/is-remote-address-the-same-as-x-forwarded-for

Comment: You could also use something like Tomcat's `RemoteIpValve` ( https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/valves/RemoteIpValve.html ) which makes this for you (i.e. it returns the `X-Forwarded-For` header value from `request.getRemoteAddr()`