# Is remote address the same as x-forwarded-for?

Tags: spring-boot, http, request, header, x-forwarded-for

I need to get the **x-forwarded-for** header from requests. Since i already have an http filter, i can easily log **remote address** using `HttpServletRequest.getRemoteAddr()`, whereas logging **x-forwarded-for** would require additional configuration. My question is, will the `HttpServletRequest.getRemoteAddr()` return the same address as **x-forwarded-for**, are **x-forwarded-for** and **remote address** the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, `HttpServletRequest.getRemoteAddr()` will return the address of the last **proxy**, or **load balancer** through which the request was sent. X-Forwarded-For will return the **original address**, from which the request was first sent, followed with the address of the **proxy** or the **load balancer**.

Comment: You could also use something like Tomcat's `RemoteIpValve` ( https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/valves/RemoteIpValve.html ) which makes this for you (i.e. it returns the `X-Forwarded-For` header value from `request.getRemoteAddr()`